# Problemas al guardar la posición del Spinner en SharedPreference

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, sharedpreferences

Estoy intentando crear un `SharedPreference` para guardar la posición de mi `Spinner` que tengo en `MiPrimeraClase` y cargar esa posición en `MiSegundaClase` pero estoy teniendo problemas o quizás lo estoy haciendo mal. O quizas es mejor utilizar una `Sqlite` (que para mi sería mejor ya que ya tengo una y la utilizo para guardar mis datos).

Os enseño mis avances y como lo estoy intentando hacer.

Este es mi `Spinner` en `MiPrimeraClase`: Donde quiero guardar la posición

```
public class MiPrimeraClase extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private String[] zodiaco;
    private Spinner spin;
    int flags[] = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher};
    Button btn1;

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        spin.setSelection(position);

        /// guardo la posición en SharedPreference
        position = spin.getSelectedItemPosition();
        SharedPreference a = new SharedPreference(getApplicationContext());
        a.guardarPosicionSpinner(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mi_primera_clase);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerzodiaco);
        zodiaco = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos_zodiaco);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), flags, zodiaco);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);


 // boton para ir a MiSegundaClase

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent prueba = new Intent(MiPrimeraClase.this, MiSegundaClase.class);
                startActivity(prueba);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Aquí `MiSegundaClase` que es donde quiero cargar la posición del `Spinner`

```
public class MiSegundaClase extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private String[] zodiaco;
    private Spinner spin;
    int flags[] = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher};

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        spin.setSelection(position);
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mi_segunda_clase);

        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerzodiaco);
        zodiaco = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos_zodiaco);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), flags, zodiaco);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        // cargo la posición de mi Spinner desde SharedPreference

        SharedPreference b = new SharedPreference(getApplicationContext());
        spin.setSelection(b.cargaPosicionSpinner());
    }
}
```

Y por último `SharedPreference` es la primera vez que creo una de cero y puede que este haciéndolo mal.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class SharedPreference {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "SharedPreferenceApp";

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context ctx;
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;

    public SharedPreference(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public int cargaPosicionSpinner(){
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int position= prefs.getInt("spnCalorieRange",-1);
        return position;
    }

    public void guardarPosicionSpinner(int position){
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        prefEditor.putInt("spnCalorieRange",position);
        prefEditor.apply();
    }
}
```

No he añadido mi `CustomAdapter` del `Spinner` porque creo que no es necesario.

Cuando abro mi aplicación se cierra, mirando el `logcat` obtengo lo siguiente:

```
02-23 16:25:04.566 25247-25247/otrointento.tres E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: otrointento.tres, PID: 25247
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor.putInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at otrointento.tres.SharedPreference.guardarPosicionSpinner(SharedPreference.java:27)
                                                                      at otrointento.tres.MiPrimeraClase.onItemSelected(MiPrimeraClase.java:25)
                                                                      at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:931)
                                                                      at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:920)
                                                                      at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(AdapterView.java)
                                                                      at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:890)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano y guiarme un poco? Gracias a todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vayamos por partes. Lo primero que veo que haces esto:

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Y ahi el problema es que this apunta a tu clase y necesita a puntar al contexto de tu aplicacion. Eso lo puedes solucionar pasandole dicho contexto en la cabecera de la funcion, algo asi:

```
public void cargaPosicionSpinner(Context ctx){
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
```

De todos modos estas haciendo algo raro en como cargas y lees del sharedpreferences. Te adjunto un pequeño codigo de como lo haria yo:

```
public class sharedPreference {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "SharedPreferenceApp";
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context ctx;

    public sharedPreference(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public void cargaPosicionSpinner(){
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int position= prefs.getInt("spnCalorieRange",-1);
        if(spinnerValue > -1)
            spin.setSelection(position);
    }

    public void guardarPosicionSpinner(int position){
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        prefEditor.putInt("spnCalorieRange",position);
        prefEditor.apply();
    }
}
```

Para usarlo tienes que llamar a la clase tal que asi:

```
sharedPreference a = new sharedPreference(getApplicationContext());
```

De lo contrario no te va a funcionar ni de lejos.

Y en cuanto a los errores:

```
Error:(21, 12) error: cannot find symbol variable spinnerValue
Error:(22, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable spin
```

es normal que no te funcione, esos valores no estan definidos en tu clase sharedPreferences. Estas intentando acceder a un spinner desde un sitio donde no esta definido. Este codigo:

```
if(spinnerValue > -1)
            spin.setSelection(position);
```

podrias cambiarlo por:

```
if(position> -1)
            spin.setSelection(position);
```

pero no te va a funcionar porque spin esta definido en tu activity y no en esta clase sharedPreferences. Si que puedes hacer es que desde tu clase devolver ese valor y cargarlo en el activity. Algo asi:

```
public int cargaPosicionSpinner(){
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int position= prefs.getInt("spnCalorieRange",-1);

        return position;
    }
```

y en el artivity hacer esto:

```
// cargo la posición de mi Spinner desde SharedPreference

        SharedPreference b = new SharedPreference(getApplicationContext());
        spin.setSelection(b.cargaPosicionSpinner());
```

No se si me explico y si me entiendes. Realmente veo que estes un poco pez en esto, y no lo digo como un critica, todo lo contrario, pero te recomendaria leer mas sobre Android y Java.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos.

Comment: Lo primero muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Curro he actualizado mi pregunta con lo que me has comentado, sigo teniendo problemas al compilar, si puedes échale un ojo, muchas gracias nuevamente, perdón pero es la primera vez hago esta función.

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta. Leela y me cuentas.

Comment: He vuelto a editar mi pregunta, se me cierra al abrir la aplicación, no me lo tomo como crítica, soy nueva en esto, no llevo más de mes y poco, y he aprendido de momento lo básico, me encanta aprender y mejorar, es la primera vez que intento crear una `SharedPreference` he estado leyendo para ver como podría hacerla y como has visto con muchos errores, pero poco a poco iré mejorando! Personas como tú me ayudáis mucho en esta magnifica página, Gracias! @Curro

Comment: Hola otra vez. Esta ya es mas sencilla. Tu estas haciendo **prefEditor.putInt("spnCalorieRange",position);** y prefsEditor es una variable sin inicializar ya que tu editor de preferencias lo has llamado **editor** tal y como pone aqui **SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();**.
Tienes que hacer **editor.putInt("spnCalorieRange",position);** y desde luego despues **editor.apply()** pero no usar prefsEditor porque no es nada.
Ahora ya deberías poder ejecutar sin problema, pero de lo contrario, por aqui andamos.

Comment: Perfecto! Solucionado, muchas gracias por la ayuda y por enseñarme como arreglar mi error!  Marco como útil y +1 ! @Curro

Comment: Un placer poder ayudarte, y para cualquier otra duda por aqui andamos muchos para ayudar. Saludos.